# SwiftでUILongPressGestureRecognizerの設定方法が変わったのか？

Tags: swift

swiftで UILongPressGestureRecognizerの簡単なテストをしてみました。
objective-cではうまく長押しを検出してくれたのですが、
swiftでは、firstLの長押しを検出しませんでした。

このコードのどこに問題があるのでしょうか？

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstL: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondL: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let gest = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "press:")


        gest.minimumPressDuration = 0.5

        firstL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)

        secondL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)

    }

    func press(sender : UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
        if let bb = sender.view as? UIButton {
         　　println "yes"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

同じ内容のプログラムを、Objective-Cで書いても、やはり「firstL」ボタンは、ロングプレスに反応しません。
理由は、**ひとつのUIGestureRecognizer（サブクラス）のインスタンスは、ひとつのUIView（サブクラス）のインスタンスにしか登録できない**からだと考えられます。

```
firstL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)

secondL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)
```

このように連続して登録すると、先に登録したほうがキャンセルされてしまうんでしょう。

```
firstL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)

// secondL.addGestureRecognizer(gest)
```

secondLのほうの登録を削除すると、firstLは、ロングプレスに反応します。
この点は、Objective-Cで書いても、まったく同じ結果になります。